# Java 8: how to convert plain UTF-8 text into RTF (with symbols > 127)?

Tags: java, rtf, richtext

I've found many "how to RTF -> plain text" with RTFEditorKit, but no one "plain->rtf".
I wouldn't to do it manually, because in my case we have to convert all chars over than 128 to hex strings to get correct RTF file. I would want to do it with some library.

I'm trying to do it with RTFEditorKit:

```
String orig = "Hello Привет こんにちは";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(orig.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
// String tmpStr = is.getText("UTF-8"); // here is correct tmpStr

RTFEditorKit rtfParser = new RTFEditorKit();
javax.swing.text.Document doc = rtfParser.createDefaultDocument();

rtfParser.read(is, doc, 0); 
int docLen = doc.getLength(); // !!! here is docLen = 0

OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
rtfParser.write(os, doc, 0, docLen, );
```

But cannot read plain text into Document object.

Comment: From looking at these places: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Character_encoding https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html  https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding - you may be able to just do it with Charset and use the appropriate windows codepage (windows-1250 etc) - perhaps no libraries at all.

Comment: JGFMK,
Yes, I'v read about it, it was my Plan B, to do it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I can pinpoint where things are going wrong in your code but this works for me. I insert the string into the `Document`:

```
String orig = "Hello Привет こんにちは";

RTFEditorKit rtfParser = new RTFEditorKit();
javax.swing.text.Document doc = rtfParser.createDefaultDocument();

doc.insertString(0, orig, null); 
int docLen = doc.getLength(); 

OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("test.rtf"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

rtfParser.write(os, doc, 0, docLen);
```

Comment: Thank you Alex! 
"doc.insertString(0, orig, null)" works well.